# How to add a space into textbox

Tags: javascript

Im sure it is something so simple but my function is returning "1" instead of just a space "" into my textbox.

```
<td><input type="button" value="Space" name="Space" onClick='document.firstChild.search.value = document.firstChild.search.value.substring(0,document.firstChild.search.value.length*1) +1'/></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the `+1` you have at the end of the code:

```
<td><input type="button" value="Space" name="Space" onClick='document.firstChild.search.value = document.firstChild.search.value.substring(0,document.firstChild.search.value.length*1) +1'/></td>
(scroll to see it)                                                                                                                                                                      ^^
```

Comment: but what do I change it to get a space?